# Difference between resumeAfter and startAtOperationTime in MongoDB change streams

Tags: mongodb, changestream

With version 4, MongoDB change streams can use two distinct parameters for specifying where to recover the change stream: `resumeAfter` (some internal token) and `startAtOperationTime`, a timestamp type.

Is it possible to completely replace `resumeAfter` with `startAtOperationTime` for a safe recovery of change streams by using the `clusterTime` found in every change event?

What I am particularly concerned about and where I couldn't find exact information in the documentation is whether for `startAtOperationTime` same rules and guarantees apply for what can be resumed and for how long. Is the operation time used here persisted correctly and can it always be used as a replacement for the document token usually used for `resumeAfter`?

Comment: Is the [documentation not explicit enough?](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/) *"resumeAfter is mutually exclusive with startAtOperationTime."*. Which means you **either use one or the other** but **never both**. Also *"The starting point for the change stream. If the specified starting point is in the past, it must be in the time range of the oplog. To check the time range of the oplog, see `rs.printReplicationInfo()`.". So essentially **anything** as long as it's within the current oplog range. Not sure what else there is to answer.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for the explanation. I know that they are mutually exclusive, but I don't know whether the same guarantees apply regarding what can be resumed. I will update the question to make this more clear.

Comment: It might not have stood out, but what I gave you there in the comment in between the `""` was actually a quotation from the manual page, and linked. There is no **guarantee** with either form. You are either asking for something that is presently in the oplog or you are not, hence the recommendation to "check the time range" as stated directly in the documentation.

Comment: Ok, stated differently: are the chances higher to recover correctly with one of the two alternatives (for instance thinking about clock shifts or effects like that).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is the operation time used here persisted correctly and can it always be used as a replacement for the document token usually used for resumeAfter?

Which of the two to use, depends on your use case.

The two options, [resumeAfter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#resumeafter-for-change-streams) and `startAtOperationTime`, are quite similar with subtle differences:

- `startAtOperationTime` takes a timestamp. While `resumeAfter` takes the *entire* `_id` of a [Change Stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) event document.
- `startAtOperationTime` can resume notifications after an [invalidate event](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/#change-event-invalidate) by creating a new change stream. While `resumeAfter` unable to resume a change stream after an invalidate event closes the stream.
- `startAtOperationTime` resumes changes that occurred **at or after** the specified timestamp. While `resumeAfter` resumes changes immediately **after** the provided token.

Whichever one you choose, either token or timestamp should be within the [Replica Set Oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) window time. Change stream relies on MongoDB global logical clock (cluster time) which is sync'd with the distributed `oplog`, so either options are using the same underlying technology.

Worth noting if you would like to start watching a collection and processing existing entries within the collection, you can specify `startAtOperationTime` with a constructed timestamp. It would be harder to do this with `resumeAfter`, as it requires a token that originates from `_id` of an event.

Also, new in MongoDB v4.2 there is a new option `startAfter` which takes an `_id` from an event, and resumes a change stream after the operation specified in the resume token. In addition, it allows notifications to resume after an invalidate event much like `startAtOperationTime`.

You may also find the [compatibility table between resume tokens](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/#resumability) on MongoDB versions useful

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. That finally clarifies my question. Would be nice to see such a detailed explanation also in the official docs.